# Project wide report in RubyMine for code style, spelling, etc?

Tags: rubymine

In the RubyMine editor, it flags things like ruby style issues, possible spelling errors, etc. I am looking for a way in RubyMine to get a whole project wide report of these coding issues. Does such a thing exist within RubyMine (or something added to RubyMine)? If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in the main menu: Code | Inspect Code...